# Setup Middleware to Handle 401 Status

Tags: node.js

I am using NodeJS v18.16.1 with Express v4.18.2.

I have the following middleware method setup, the intention is that anytime I respond with a 401 I want it to redirect to login and optionally set the error message in the query string parameter:

```js
const redirectUnauthorized = (request, response, next) => {
    if (response.statusCode === 401) {
        const errorMessage = request.body;
        let url = '/login';
        if (errorMessage) {
            url += `?error=${request.body}`;
        }
        return response.redirect(url)
    } else {
        next();
    }
};
app.use(redirectUnauthorized);

const controllerAuth = require(path.join(__dirname, 'api', 'auth.js'))
app.post('/api/auth/login', controllerAuth.login);
```

And this is my /api/auth.js login method:

```js
const login = (request, response) => {
    if (request.method !== 'POST') {
        return response.status(405).send('Method not allowed');
    }

    const formData = request.body;
    if (!formData) {
        return response.status(400).send('No body was sent');
    }
    formData.ReturnUrl = formData.ReturnUrl || 'users'

    if (formData.Username === 'admin' && formData.Password === 'admin') {
        return response.redirect(`./${formData.ReturnUrl}`);
    } else {
        return response.status(401).send('Invalid username and/or password.');
    }
};
```

The intention of this method is that it must be a POST, it must contain a body, and the username/password must be admin/admin (for testing purposes, obviously this isn't my authentication business logic). If the last bit of business logic fails, I want it to return a 401 with the error message.

When I POST admin/admin it works just fine and I'm redirected. However, when I POST admin/foo it returns the error message in the browser rather than redirecting back to login with the error message in the query string parameter.

What am I missing here?

---

**Update**

Replacing the if/else at the end of my login method to the following works:

```js
if (formData.Username === 'admin' && formData.Password === 'admin') {
    return response.redirect(`/${formData.ReturnUrl}`);
}
return response.status(401).send('<script>window.location.href = "/login?error=Invalid username and/or password"</script>');
```

But this doesn't quite seem right to me. Is this the right approach?

Comment: Since `app.use` is called before `app.post`, `redirectUnauthorized` run first, then call `next`, which is `login`. Finally `login` returns `response.status(401).send('...')`, no redirect here. So the behaviour you describe is expected. The middleware is already run, it will not go back and run again for the same request.

Comment: Your so called "middleware" is actually not doing what a middleware suppose to do. Your `redirectUnauthorized` is some response decision logic that should be put within or after `login`. A "middleware" is used to inspect/pre-process the request, e.g. guard all requests by validating authentication token and redirect to login page without passing the request to the endpoint if the authentication token is invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve my own question. I setup a POST method for login which does the following:

```js
router.post('/', async (request, response) => {
    try {
        const payload = request.body || {};
        const returnUrl = request.body.ReturnUrl || '/users';
        const userId = await authDomain.login(payload);

        request.session.userId = userId;
        response.redirect(302, returnUrl);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        response.redirect(302, `/login?error=${error}`);
    }
});
```

Then I updated my middleware to the following:

```js
const requireAuth = (request, response, next) => {
    if (request.url.indexOf('/logout') === 0) {
        next();
    } else if (request.session.userId && request.url.indexOf('/login') !== 0) {
        next();
    } else if (request.session.userId) {
        response.redirect('/users');
    } else if (request.url.indexOf('/login') !== 0) {
        response.redirect('/login');
    } else {
        next();
    }
};
```

Basically what this does is either redirect to `/users` or `/login` with an error based on if a login is successful. Then when NodeJS executes the middleware, it checks if:

1. The requested URL is `/logout`. If so, then continue.
2. The authorization session cookie is set and the requested URL is not `/login`. If so, then continue.
3. The authorization session cookie is set and the requested URL is `/login`. If so, then redirect to `/users`.
4. The authorization session cookie is not set and the requested URL is not `/login`. If so, then redirect to `/login`.
5. Anything else, then continue.